# Is manifesting Haram in Islam

Tags: halal-haram

Is manifesting Haram in Islam I’m confused because I’ve read it’s Haram and not Haram in many different places

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and our model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. If you have something to share that would be much better, at least I'm unclear about what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Manifesting like subliminals? It's a sign of arrogance (even if it's not intended) because for manifesting you have to believe that just by changing your mind you can change reality (Like getting more money, attracting good luck, etc).

Also see [here](https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/361732/truth-about-subliminal-messaging-as-source-of-power)

and Allah knows best